# Can only run one project from Android Studio. Additional project fail to run apk. Ok with IntelliJIDEA

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2. Also I am using a Mobile Phone as the device on USB. Once I have build a project, and run it all is fine.

But when I build a complete different project and try the same, as soon as it wants to install the apk on the phone, I get a message saying:

> Installation failed with Message INSTALLED_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling the existing version of the apk...

But the application has never been installed on the phone in the first place.

I can read:

> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

So I click OK on the Message box (even though it has never been installed). So after I click OK I read following error:

> $ adb shell pm uninstall com.example
>   DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
>   Error while Installing APK

It seems as if Android Studio gets confused and thinks the new project is the same as the old one stored on the phone.

I have un-installed the first application and set the phone back to factory default setting, and then re-activated developer mode, but to no avail. I cannot run any other project except the first one I have run.

If I use one of my older IntelliJIDEA instead my ANDROID STUDIO I have no issues at all.

Message Box Prompt:

[image: Message Box Prompt]

Answer (score 0):

Android uses package names to identify apps. There may only be one app with a particular package name installed on the device at once, and you are likely signing the apps with different keys, hence Android prevents you from replacing the old app with the new one.

To fix the problem, you should change `com.example` to something that is unique to the particular project you're building.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this further and post back.

Answer (score 0):

This issue simply stopped.
More details to the initial problem:
I never managed to install the apk by running Android Studio in the first place but it insisted it needed uninstalling.

Initially I had two phones (the second one has broken down in the meantime). On the first phone I had the apk of "Project one" installed first.  The installation of the second project and any subsequent project gave me the issue as explained in this post, even if uninstalling all projects from the phone did not solve anything.

On the second phone, I had the apk of "Project two" installed first and project two worked fine. The installation of the first project and any subsequent project gave me the issue as posted, even if uninstalling all projects from the phone did not solve anything.

I must also point out that the failing installations were never installed on the phone in the first place. I never got it to the point of installing it in the first place. So there was nothing to uninstall.

Uninstalling and even resetting the phone to factory setting and then restarting made absolutely no difference.

I spend days pulling my hair over this. Even using something different than com.example made no difference.
When I tried to change the Compile SDK version to Google APIs (API 23) and then changed it back again to the API 23 Version 6.0 Marshmallow the issue simply dissipated for good.

Because this was just a quick test project, I was trying to build a number of them to get the error back - to no avail - all good.

I was trying to recreate the problem by making the project again exactly as it was also considering your two posts. But it works fine.

Android Version of my phone is 5.1. 
Compile SKD version is 6.0
Min SDK version is 4.4 Kit Kat
Target SDK is 6.0 Marshmallow

It seems fine now, but I am not happy about it. Thanks for your response, I truly appreciate you trying to help me. I will come back if I get this problem back.

I wished I could pin point the cause of this nightmare.

My Setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drpWB.jpg

Answer (score -1):

At the worst, your code maybe calling code lines that ARE NOT SUPPORTED IN THE CURRENT PLATFORM RELEASE. So if you are trying to call some routines that work on JellyBean, and were designed to work for platforms >= JellyBeans, those routines are destined to NEVER WORK on platforms < JellyBeans.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this further and post back.